# PHP Regex help - using nearer word from list as a boundry instead of provided in-list order

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a problem with one regex expression to be used so i.e. the input string looks like

`hello world and me or you`

and I would like to match all from hello until the closest/nearest of the noisy words: `and,or`

so far I have come up with something like that:

`preg_match_all("/^hello[A-Z0-9 -]*(or|and)/is",$string,$match);`

but the problem is that it will return: 
`hello world and me or` instead of `hello world and` since the `or` is first in 
`(or|and)` list.

It would be really appreciated if anyone could tell me is there an option to tell regex engine to check which one is closer/nearer from the OR tokens list to match and used that one instead of checking the order as provided i.e. `(or|and)` in which case and should be used as its closer to initial pattern.

P.S.
changing an order inside `(or|and)` is not a solution as there are more words and you never know which one is nearer so it must be done on the algorithmic level.

many thanks for your advices.

Comment: If the strings are not very long, you could preg_split() them at (and|or) and then process the parts individually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question mark after an asterisk (ie. `/.*?/`) tells the asterisked expression to be not greedy.
So your RegExp should be `/^hello[A-Z0-9 -]*?(or|and)/is` or something similar.

Comment: Correct, I'd put also word boundaries or you risk matching hello wor

Comment: @piotrm Yep, this extends it to `/^(hello[A-Z0-9 -]*?)\b(or|and)/is`

Comment: I just recognised it also could be the other side... so the correct one is `/^(hello[A-Z0-9 -]*?)\b(or|and)\b/is`

Answer (score 0):

Use [(capturing) subpatterns](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php):

```
preg_match_all("/^(hello[A-Z0-9 -]*)(or|and)/is",$string,$match);
```

and `$match[0][1]`, `$match[1][1]`, `$match[2][1]` ... will contain the values as you need 'em.